# Plone logo not appearing on mobile devices such as iPod

Tags: plone, ipod, graphical-logo

I'm adding responsive styles for our website built in Plone 4 CMS and testing on an old iPod 2 device. When viewing on this device, the logo.png does not display. [Plone.org](http://plone.org) top left logo has similar problem and does not appear on this device. Other Plone websites tested have logos appearing.

I've changed the logo to a different format, i.e. logo.gif, and logo.jpg in the 'base_properties.props' file with no improved results. I was careful to ensure spelling of logo files was accurate.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have your checked portal_css? I think one of the default stylesheets is conditional on screen width, maybe the logo gets hidden there. (I assume you've checked that `.../logo.png`, called directly as an URL, does give the picture.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explicitly removed in the mobile.css file:

https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.sunburst/blob/master/plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_styles/mobile.css#L11

`#portal-logo {
 display: none;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to add the icon to a link object in the  element.

Take a look at http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2011/01/31/adding-favicons-for-moble-safari-web-sites-ipodiphoneipad/

This could be done by customizing the main_template or by customizing/adding a viewlet that is in the head.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help. This was added in the main_template.pt: '<link rel="mobile-logo" tal:attributes="href string:${portal_url}/logo.png" />' but in testing the page on the iPod, we're not seeing the logo. After doing this we re-imported the theme in portal_setup in the ZMI. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Where'd you get the rel="mobile-logo" from? Shouldn't it be rel="apple-touch-icon" like it is on the article I linked?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you "re-imported" the thing, but that has nothing to do with it. Just customizing main_template is all you need.